# Value of column in row with previous key

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm writing an application which tracks views of various items across time, and I've hit a bit of a snag. I need to get the difference in views between two adjacent updates. The updates are identified by a `UNIQUE` key, containing the columns `time` and `id`. How would I be able to do this, without running multiple queries?

```
SELECT updates.views, (updates.views - <previous views>) 
FROM updates JOIN stuff ON stuff.id = stuff.id 
WHERE updates.time = '01-01-1970 00:00:00' AND stuff.owner = 'someone'
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: So your 'updates' table has a views column too?

Comment: Can you list your tables?  Given the (brief) problem description, I don't understand what "stuff" is — it looks like you should only be using the table "updates".  Additionally, is there a way to identify the previous "updates" row or is it defined as the row with the same id and the greatest time less than the time in the current row?

Comment: "updates# tracks the views, "stuff" only contains information about, the, um, stuff (title, URLs, etc.). "stuff" doesn't have any information about views. This is only a highly-stripped down testcase, the real thing is too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in pretty much any RDBMS:

```
SELECT
     UPD.id,
     UPD.views,
     (UPD.views - COALESCE(LAST_UPD.views, 0))
FROM
     Updates UPD
INNER JOIN Stuff S ON
     S.id = UPD.id AND
     S.owner = 'someone'
INNER JOIN Updates LAST_UPD ON
     LAST_UPD.id = UPD.id AND
     LAST_UPD.time < UPD.time
LEFT OUTER JOIN Updates UPD2 ON
     UPD2.id = LAST_UPD.id AND
     UPD2.time < UPD.time AND
     UPD2.time > LAST_UPD.time
WHERE
     UPD2.id IS NULL AND
     UPD.time = '01-01-1970 00:00:00'
```

What you're basically doing is saying, "Give me a previous update (LAST_UPD.time < UPD.time) for which there are no other updates after it and before this one (the left join and UPD2.id IS NULL).

Comment: Uh, nothing is NULL. All columns are NOT NULL.

Comment: @Electro: The condition `UPD2.id IS NULL` says that there can't be rows between `LAST_UPD` and `UPD`.  It doesn't say a column must be null; it says that the third JOIN must fail

Comment: Correct Andomar. I'll update my response to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could select the previous maximum in a subquery:

```
SELECT     updates.views
,          (updates.views - (
               select max(prevupd.views) 
               from updates prevupd 
               where prevupd.id <> updates.id
           ))
FROM updates 
JOIN stuff ON stuff.id = stuff.id 
WHERE updates.time = '01-01-1970 00:00:00' 
AND stuff.owner = 'someone'
```

Some example data would be nice, as Larry Lustig suggests.

Answer (score 1):

In `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  views - LAG(views) OVER (ORDER BY time, id)
FROM    updates
JOIN    stuff
ON      stuff.id = updates.stuffid 
WHERE   updates.time = '01-01-1970 00:00:00'
        AND stuff.owner = 'someone'
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  views - @pviews AS diff,
        @pviews := views
FROM    (
        SELECT  @pviews := NULL
        ) vars
CROSS JOIN
        updates
JOIN    stuff
ON      stuff.id = updates.stuffid 
WHERE   updates.time = '01-01-1970 00:00:00'
        AND stuff.owner = 'someone'
ORDER BY
        time, id
```